# Passing a Parameter to Controller from View on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a System to Upvote Posts using CodeIgniter. Since the posts would be Dynamic, I want the Post ID to be returned to the Controller class on Button Click.

**View**

```
<button type="button" name="upvoteButton" class="btn btn-success" value="<?php echo $postList[$i]->postId; ?>" onclick="window.location='<?php echo site_url("Home/upvotePost");?>'">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span> <?php echo $postList[$i]->upvotes; ?>
</button>
```

**Controller**

```
public function upvotePost($id) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('".$id."')</script>";
}
```

How do I capture the *Value* of the button depicted here? Thank you.

Comment: `Home/upvotePost/id` will work or use a form

Comment: @FastSnail It worked. Thank you!